# Switching to normal mode requires Shift in addition to ESC

Tags: macos, vim

I have always used `<Esc>` for switching mode to Normal mode (from Insert mode).
Now I have a new macbook and I need to use `<shift-Esc>` to switch modes (also working with `<Ctrl-[>` )
How can I configure it to only ESC key?

I tried to use `inoremap` in .vimrc file to remap, but it does not work, probably I did not use it correctly.

```
inoremap <Esc> <Shift-Esc>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation shown when executing the command `:help :map-which-keys`, in order to use the `Shift` key in a mapping, for example as `<Shift-Esc>` as you are trying to do, it must be specified as `<S-...>`.

So in your case, changing the `<Shift-Esc>` in your mapping to `<S-Esc>` should work as you intend.

Alternatively, mapping the `<Esc>` key to `<C-[>` instead of `<S-Esc>` should provide the same solution.